# I am using AsyncTask for a splashscreen and database load in multiplaces. Is this a good idea?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I have a splash screen and main activity. The idea is to show the splash while doing db loads. I can not use the emulation mode as is does not work the same as a apk install directly on the phone. When the APK installs the splash screen shows for 5 seconds then the db listview screen shows. This is correct. But when I press the application launch icon on the phone the splash does not appear, a white screen shows for the splash screen time and then the db listview appears.  Here are the associated files, will supply more if needed:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.loadrunner"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.loadrunner.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.loadrunner.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
package com.loadrunner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SPLASH_SHOW_TIME = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new BackgroundSplashTask().execute();
}
/*@Override
protected void onStart(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new BackgroundSplashTask().execute();
}*/
/**
 * Async Task: can be used to load DB, images during which the splash screen
 * is shown to user
 */
private class BackgroundSplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        // I have just give a sleep for this thread
        // if you want to load database, make
        // network calls, load images
        // you can do here and remove the following
        // sleep

        // do not worry about this Thread.sleep
        // this is an async task, it will not disrupt the UI
        try {
            Thread.sleep(SPLASH_SHOW_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        // any info loaded can during splash_show
        // can be passed to main activity using
        // below
        i.putExtra("loaded_info", " ");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

}
}


package com.loadrunner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.Table.TableMainLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";
public static DatabaseHandler db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//*************************************************************************************************
    // remove title bar.
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //splash

    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //splash

    /* Loads next module */
    // get the splash image
    //ImageView splashImage = (ImageView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplashLogo); //splash
    //ImageView splashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplashLogo); //splash
    //Log.d("Loadrunner", "splashImage: " + splashImage);
    //splashImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.shoppingcart);

    // make the splash image invisible
    //splashImage.setVisibility(View.GONE); //splash
    // splashImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //splash

    // specify animation
    //Animation animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.splash_screen_fadeout); //splash

    // apply the animattion
    //splashImage.startAnimation(animFadeOut); //splash
//*************************************************************************************************

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    db.getWritableDatabase();
    this.db.insertFast(100);
    int dbreccnt = db.countRecords();
    Log.d("AppLoadrunner ", "Loadrunner record count " + dbreccnt);
    setContentView(new TableMainLayout(this));
    Log.d("AppLoadrunner ", "Loadrunner MainActivity Content set");
}
```

}

```
package com.loadrunner;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


public class AsyncInsertData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
String type;
long timeElapsed;

protected AsyncInsertData(String type){
    this.type  = type;
    //this.databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    //(MainActivity.this);
}


//@type - can be 'normal' or 'fast'
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //tvStatus.setText("Inserting " + editTextRecordNum.getText() + " records...");
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    Log.d("AppSynch", "AsynchInsertData.java");
    try {

        // empty the table
        databaseHandler.deleteRecords();

        // keep track of execution time
        long lStartTime = System.nanoTime();

        type = "fast";
        int insertCount = 20; // This never seems to be called


        if (type.equals("normal")) {
            databaseHandler.insertNormal(insertCount);
        } else {
            databaseHandler.insertFast(insertCount);
        }

        // execution finished
        long lEndTime = System.nanoTime();

        // display execution time
        timeElapsed = lEndTime - lStartTime;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is an Android Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //tvStatus.setText("Done " + choice + " inserting " + databaseHandler.countRecords() + " records into table: [" + this.databaseHandler.tableName + "]. Time elapsed: " + timeElapsed / 1000000 + " ms.");
}
```

}

```
package com.loadrunner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.Table.TableMainLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";
public static DatabaseHandler db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//*************************************************************************************************
    // remove title bar.
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //splash

    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //splash

    /* Loads next module */
    // get the splash image
    //ImageView splashImage = (ImageView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplashLogo); //splash
    //ImageView splashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplashLogo); //splash
    //Log.d("Loadrunner", "splashImage: " + splashImage);
    //splashImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.shoppingcart);

    // make the splash image invisible
    //splashImage.setVisibility(View.GONE); //splash
    // splashImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //splash

    // specify animation
    //Animation animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.splash_screen_fadeout); //splash

    // apply the animattion
    //splashImage.startAnimation(animFadeOut); //splash
//*************************************************************************************************

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    db.getWritableDatabase();
    this.db.insertFast(100);
    int dbreccnt = db.countRecords();
    Log.d("AppLoadrunner ", "Loadrunner record count " + dbreccnt);
    setContentView(new TableMainLayout(this));
    Log.d("AppLoadrunner ", "Loadrunner MainActivity Content set");
}
```

}

Comment: You should accept an answer that helped you out the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themed splash screens might help fix this issue, the delay could be from initializing the layout. The following article shows how to set up a splash screen using styles and without calling setContentView()

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: I added this and nothing changed. I removed the finish(); onpostexecute(). That did not change the app operation either. After the inintal APK the app does what it supposed to do. After that any time the user presses the application launch icon the splashscreen never appears again. The dsblistview always appears though.

Comment: I had a suspicion yesterday about onCreate() in the splashscreenactivity. That should always work but it seems to me that oncreate() is never called again. I will put a log entry there to prove this. My machine is shut down right now.

Comment: If the app is already running it will resume the activity in the stack , if there are not activities or the process is killed thats when The app is launched with the launcher main activity, which in your case is the splash activity.

Comment: Even shutting down the phone did not clear the app. Then I though 'Well the user will see the splashscreen only once after install and it wont be in their way after that.' So with that said I will put the splashscreen in the help menu or in the background display. Always one way to skin a cat.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend that. Try this, kill the app from recent app list and try to launch again . It should launch the splash activity, if it doesnt the issue is with the logic

Comment: I have to agree with you. Another deep debugging session is necessary. But the splashscreen will be just static display screen.

Comment: I wouldn't use this solution as this breaks the Android lifecycle convention.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is because once you install the app and reopen it, app is already running. If you do not kill it before restarting it, it will resume the activity it was on rather than starting your SplashScreen. So in short, to verify that it works, try killing the app after installation OR set it up so that it shows your loading screen when it resumes (might require significant refactor). Essentially you'd need to refactor the loading from starting only in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Excellent response. I use an app killer and that did not change the launch. I then restarted the phone. That did not make a difference either. I can honestly say the app is canceled but still the splash screen does not appear. When I press the app icon only the white screen for the timer length shows and then the dblistview appears. So the same launch error. If it can be called an error. I know it to be a programming mistake somewhere. I will upvote for your response contributing good analysis.

Comment: If you properly kill the app, the code executed when the app icon is clicked   in the drawer will be identical to when you push the app to your phone when you build the apk. If something is not working the same way, you must not be killing the app correctly or something.

Comment: but how do I explain the phone restart not changing anything?

Comment: That's probably because the system preserves the stack and calls `onCreate()` of your MainActivity instead of SplashScreen Activity after you resume the app after restart. If you notice, restarting your phone doesn't reset all your previously open apps to their initial loading (or splash) screens.

Comment: Any comments on how i kill this app then to really clear the stack? I am learning more about the environment as i get into this project. Thanks.

Comment: I think this should give you a rough idea: http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-close-android-apps

Answer (score -1):

The app kill process doesnt kill this. I am on an HTC EVO. This has 4 buttons at the bottom. The HOME acts like an app switcher. It does not kill. The 3rd button is [Go back]. This works. It traverses back through the activities that havent executed a finish();. I was using the Home to quit the app. This just left it on the stack and returned to Home screen.
If I dont use the back arrow button the app never kills and I never see the splash screen.
When I run the app, from having used the home button previously, the app displays a white screen for the same time as the splashscreen timout. Its like the graphic just doesn't display. This is probably a different issue. For now I have found the initial splash screen display problem and solved it. I will have to find the activity functions that corrrelate to this behaviour. Thank you all for helping with this problem.

Comment: This is a description of what you did to get it to work, after I told you why it was behaving the way it did, which is what you asked for. You should try to avoid providing your own answers to the questions that were already answered correctly - you don't get any points for doing so, and people who spent time on your issue lose points they gained. Just FYI.